# Set random background colors for multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple div's on a page that I'd like to assign a random background color to. If possible, the colors should not repeat themselves unless I run out of colors to use. I've managed to get the div containers to load with a random color from an array, but the color is always the same for all of the remaining divs. Is there anything I can do to set the background color to a different value if the background color is already in use by another div?

Here's what I have so far (non working)

```
function shuffleColors() {
    var colors = ["bg-red", "bg-green", "bg-purple", "bg-blue"];
    var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
    // var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    var contentBlock = $('.content-block');

    for (var i = 0; i < contentBlock.length; i++) {

        if (colors[i] == colors[randomColor]) {
            colors[randomColor]++
            contentBlock.addClass(colors[randomColor]);
        }

    }
}

shuffleColors();
```

The code below shows how I managed to select a random background color, however the color is the same for all divs

```
var background = ["bg-red", "bg-green", "bg-purple", "bg-blue"];
var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*background.length);           

$('.content-block').addClass(background[randomColor]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem might be with how you are incrementing your random color:

```
colors[randomColor]++
```

That isn't the correct way. You probably just want to increment the index in the array:

```
randomColor++
```

You also need to make sure you are staying within the bounds of your color array. I would suggest using mod (%) for that:

```
randomColor = (randomColor + 1) % colors.length
```

Using jQuery to loop, you would have somethign like:

```
$(".content-block").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass(colors[randomColor]); // assign the color
    randomColor = (randomColor + 1) % colors.length; // step to the next color; this will loop to the beginning thanks to mod
});
```

Comment: You already accepted the answer, but here is a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Re5Dm/)

Answer (score 2):

You're definitely along the right lines, but you can simplify your loop and use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function to iterate over all of the `$('.content-block')` elements on your page. You're alos only setting the random colour once, so you can move that into the each function:

```
$('.content-block').each(function(i, el) {
    var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*background.length);
    $(el).addClass(background[randomColor]);
});
```

I've also just realised that you might want each `$('.content-block')` to be a different colour from the other. In which case, you want to remove the colour from `colors` each time you've assigned a colour:

```
function getRandomColour() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math,random()*colors.length();
    var randomColour = colors[randomNumber];
    var colourPosition = colors.indexOf(randomColour);

    colours.splice(colourPosition, 1); // Remove colour from array

    return randomColour;    
}

$('.content-block').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).addClass(background[randomColor]);
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work because there is no "background" array. You would need to change it to "colors". And this will still use the same random color for every div.

Answer (score 0):

change this

`contentBlock.addClass(colors[randomColor]);`

to this:

```
contentBlock[i].addClass(colors[randomColor]);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It will work 100% and it is made of pure Javascript.

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
  var div = document.getElementsByClassName("div")[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
}
```

```css
div {
 width: 200px;
 height:200px;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 margin: 15px;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
```